# downloading folder from cloud

Tags: python, artifactory, artifact

**Basic idea:** I want to get this zipped artifactory, go through with a loop open every text file and add a line and save it. After that I want to upload the new version of this folder, again as a zipped folder.

My first problem is **I cant download this zipped folder from artifactory.**

I have already tried this out: https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory

I changed the same code with my personal path, username and pw (changed it for this post because of security) but I get lots of **errors**:

UPDATE: no SSL errors anymore but I still have a problem with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be related to validation of your Artifactory SSL certificate.

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)
```

You should look at the various options which the Python interface library for JFrog Artifactory is offering for handling [SSL certificate validations](https://github.com/devopshq/artifactory#ssl-cert-verification-options).
For example disable host cert verification

```
from artifactory import ArtifactoryPath

path = ArtifactoryPath(
    "http://my-artifactory/artifactory/libs-snapshot-local/myapp/1.0", verify=False
)
```

Comment: Hi verify=False helped me with the ssl errors but I still have the same problem, that I cant download the zipped artifact. Maybe I use the wrong code (I also tried without zipped code) I always get this errors. I updated my question with my code. Could u have a look?

Comment: It works now. I just used Downloading Artifacts instead of Downloading Artifacts folder as archive and deleted the test call (it did not like it idk why) I created a test file where I did a pytest and called this function. Thanks for your help :)